# Does the Collection of Graphs not Embeddable in a Fixed Orbifold have a Well-quasi-ordering?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, geometric-topology, combinatorial-geometry, orbifolds

Using the Robertson-Seymour Theorem, one can show that given a fixed surface $S$ the collection of graphs which can't be embedded in it are defined by a finite set of forbidden minors - just as the non-planar graphs have a finite set ($K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$) of forbidden minors for embeddability.

Is the same true for $2$-dimensional compact orbifolds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying topological space of a 2-dimensional orbifold is a topological manifold with boundary. The point is that the only allowed stabilizers are cyclic groups of rotations or dihedral groups, which you can calculate model quotients of explicitly.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of a different collection of spaces that I thought was the same as orbifolds.  What is the usual generalization of manifolds that allows 'fins' and 'pinches,' e.g. finitely many copies of $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$ attached along an arc, or finitely many spheres attached at a common point?  Just finite 2-$CW$ complexes?